# Push view above when using custom Keyboard

Tags: android, view, keyboard, push

I have created a custom keyboard for my android application. I have also disabled the default android keyboard. I display the keyboard as a fragment in the activity and it shows up well.

I only cannot get activity view to push above when the keyboard shows up. Is there any way that I could do this?

**XML FILE**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

**SHOW FRAGMENT**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.flKeyboard, new Keyboard()).commit();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the keyboard at the top of your screen? Or is it just under your activity view as in layers?

Comment: Its at the top. I've added a FrameLayout the xml file, and I add the Keyboard fragment when ever required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, but I've used a translate animation, to move the view along the Y-axis. With some tweaking , it actually looks better than the default android push.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>  
<View
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />  
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myView"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows the keyboard below the view, but does not push the view up. So, I can see only a single row of the keyboard

Comment: Tried that too. It doesn't push the view above simple makes it smaller and squished.